# Problems adding items with same name to an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The expected function of the following code is to create (and return) an ArrayList with all the `U1` (another class) needed to fill all the items stored in the `loadItems` ArrayList.

- `U1` class has a boolean method called `canCarry` that returns `true` when the item weight plus the weight of all loaded items aren't greater than a specific maximum weight.
- `carry` is another `U1` method that updates the weight of all the loaded items so that we can consider that the item has been loaded and we can try with the next item.

The code I have written works when the total amount of weight doesn´t exceed  the maximum that one `U1` can handle, so **the problem is when I create a new `U1` in the `u1Needed` ArrayList**, the ArrayList that, when all the items in the `loadItems` are load up, is returned.

```java
    ArrayList<U1> loadU1() {

        ArrayList<U1> u1Needed = new ArrayList<>();
        U1 u1 = new U1();


        for (int i=0; i<=(loadItems().size()-1);) {

            if (u1.canCarry(loadItems().get(i))) {
                u1.carry(loadItems().get(i));
                i++;

            } else {
                u1Needed.add(u1);
                u1 = new U1();

            }

            if (i==(loadItems().size()-1)) {
                u1Needed.add(u1);
            }

        }

        return u1Needed;

     }
```

Comment: The thing is that you are not creating a new `U1` multiple times, just once, and add that one object to the array multiple times. Most likely you want to add many different object to it.

Comment: @Amongalen and how can I do it?

Comment: "the problem is when I create a new U1 in the u1Needed ArrayList, the ArrayList that, when all the items in the loadItems are load up, is returned." -- Then what are you supposed to be returning. Your return statement is to return```u1Needed```